# When requesting a user to the DB and wanting to add an element to a Set field of the same, I receive an error when I want to save it

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

```
package com.nahuel.apirest.entities;

import com.nahuel.apirest.models.UserBasicDTO;
import com.nahuel.apirest.models.UserDTO;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_auth")
public class  User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "user_sequence",
            sequenceName = "user_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1,
            initialValue = 10000
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "user_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "cellphone")
    private int cellphone;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Business> businesses = new HashSet<>();


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return id != null && Objects.equals(id, user.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
}
```

```
package com.nahuel.apirest.entities;


import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;

import java.util.Objects;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "business")
public class Business {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "business_sequence",
            sequenceName = "business_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1,
            initialValue = 3000
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "business_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private User user;
}
```

```
    public ResponseEntity<String> create(String token, BusinessDTO businessData) {

        String emailUser = jwtService.extractUsername(token.replace("Bearer ", ""));
        Optional<User> userLogin = userRepository.findByEmail(emailUser);
        if(userLogin.isPresent()){
            User user = userLogin.get();

            Business newBusiness = businessRepository.save(new Business(null, businessData.getName(),user));

            user.setBusinesses(Set.of(newBusiness));

            userRepository.save(userUpdated);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("add success");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }
```

```
ERROR

23-02-18T20:47:09.356-03:00 ERROR 21711 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException] with root cause

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections.uoe(ImmutableCollections.java:142) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$AbstractImmutableCollection.clear(ImmutableCollections.java:149) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:525) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:705) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:117) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:490) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:830) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:816) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy112.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:307) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy112.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:613) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:288) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:163) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy116.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.nahuel.apirest.services.BusinessServices.create(BusinessServices.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.nahuel.apirest.controllers.BusinessController.addBusiness(BusinessController.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at com.nahuel.apirest.config.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:55) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I tried executing the same functions directly in a CommandRunner and it worked

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at `org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:525)`, which collection is having `clear` called on it? Did you create that collection? If so, could you have created it differently so that `clear` would succeed?

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the error message, I am a little worried about your use of `Set.of(newBusiness)`. `Set.of` creates an *immutable* set, which is probably not what you want in the long run whether it causes this error or not.

I also don't see why your `create` method compiles, because `userUpdated` is not defined locally.

Comment: The problem is that this error appears when the user is fetched from the DB, if I create a new user, and then add his business, no error occurs